# Activitate Voice Dictation from Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, voice-dictation

Getting to know my new iPad and I really like the voice dictation, but I can't figure out how to activate it from my Apple Bluetooth Keyboard. My workaround is to turn off the keyboard so I get the onscreen version. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 5.1, Voice Dictation is not capable of being started from external keyboards.

There is a workaround.  The solution is that when you want to dictate, press the <kbd>⏏</kbd> key (eject) on your external keyboard.  This should bring up the virtual keyboard on the screen, from which you can then start dictation.

Note: *This key doesn't work like other function keys until you have tapped into a text entry field and have the flashing cursor.*

Comment: @HenrikBennetsen: Not a problem!

Comment: this did not work on my zag keyboard that key closes the app.

Answer (score 1):

#### Press <kbd>^ Control</kbd> Twice to Activate

As of iOS 15<sup>*</sup> Dictation is enabled by default and the default action is to double press <kbd>^ Control</kbd> to activate it.

I tested this on  two different Bluetooth keyboards (Logitech K380 and a Keychron K8) with iPadOS 16 and after pairing each, dictation was already enabled.  However, you can manually toggle this setting, if necessary, by going to ***Settings → General → Keyboard*** then toggle ***Enable Dictation***.  You can also choose a different dictation shortcut, if necessary.

---

<sup>*</sup> Per Apple’s Support Document [Dictate text while using Magic Keyboard with iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/dictate-text-iph24206370d/15.0/ios/15.0), it shows to be valid for iOS 15 and 16. Further research is needed to verify if earlier versions of iOS supported this feature.

Comment: This is great! I was actually wondering this a few days ago. Thanks for the tip!  Now if I can figure out punctuation

Comment: Where do you explain any of this @Thinkr. The question is “How to activate **from** a Bluetooth keyboard** not from the screen.

Comment: *You never answered the actual question being asked* @Thinkr  Saying that a single line being where the setting is located does not  make these similar.  Again, the question was “How to activate **from** the keyboard” not *how to enable and activate from the screen*.

Answer (score 0):

press the keyboard tab (first line) when you want to switch between keyboards. They mic will work after that. I have a Logitech bluetooth keyboard on my Ipad Air 2. I hope it helps.

Comment: Where is that keyboard tab?

Comment: Press and Hold the Down Arrow / Chevron at the bottom of the screen so the On Screen keyboard comes up, then press Dictation Button...

Comment: @geilt This does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

There is an way to do this that does not require you to show the on-screen keyboard.

Go to **Settings** > **General** > **Keyboards** and turn on "Enable Dictation".

[image: Turn on "Enable Dictation" in Settings > Genral > Keyboards]

You should see something like this when wanting to write somewhere :

[image]

Simply tap the microphone button (see image on top) to start dictating, tap it again when you're finished.