# Can the iPad magic keyboard start dictation with a shortcut command?

Tags: ios, keyboard, voice-dictation, ipados

I want a physical keyboard shortcut to enable dictation on iPadOS.

I have two iPads Pro - one with the smart folio physical keyboard and another with the magic keyboard.  Ideally without moving my hands from the physical keyboard, tab to any text input and hold keys to activate the voice input button on the physical keyboard.

For now, I have to tap twice on the caret bottom right than tap on the mic button on the on-screen keyboard.

[image: Annotated on-screen keyboard for iPad showing taps to get to voice dictation]

Is there a built in key shortcut for this or a way to add that using Accessibility to settings on iPadOS 13.5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activitate Voice Dictation from Bluetooth Keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46059/activitate-voice-dictation-from-bluetooth-keyboard)

Comment: No @Allan - The Magic Keyboard is very much not a bluetooth keyboard so I need to  research whether the answer here is workable or not and then decide if the close is appropriate or not and have details on if I want to reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in iPadOS 13.5 but on later versions, you can enable this by pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> or <kbd>^ Control</kbd> two times (<kbd>^ Control</kbd> is the default).

To choose the key with which dictation could be enabled, go to *Settings > General > Keyboard > Dictation Shortcut*. From there, choose the one you want.

[image]